# What's the advantage of uwsgi protocol over http for Apache proxying?

Tags: apache2, uwsgi

I've just set up a couple of WSGI apps behind an Apache server proxying to uwsgi using UNIX sockets on the same host. The generally advertised method to do that seems to be like this:

```
Apache config:
ProxyPass / unix:/var/lib/uwsgi/app1.sock|uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-app1/

uwsgi .ini
socket = /var/lib/uwsgi/app1.sock
```

I've done it a bit differently:

```
Apache config:
ProxyPass / unix:/var/lib/uwsgi/app1.sock|http://127.0.0.1/

uwsgi .ini
http-socket = /var/lib/uwsgi/app1.sock
```

So basically in my setup Apache and uwsgi talk back and forth using http instead of uwsgi's native protocol. To me the advantages are that I save one extra dependency (mod_proxy_uwsgi), and that it was easier to debug the whole setup by being able to directly talk to the uwsgi server using curl --unix-socket

So what is the advantage of using the uwsgi protocol? If it's only about performance -- no issue for my low-volume applications.

Answer (score 0):

mod_proxy_uwsgi is included with apache2 since some years now, so should not be "an extra dependency".

Yes, replacing http with [the uWSGI protocol](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Protocol.html) is (in itself) only an efficiency benefit. Other parts of uWSGI - like the use of a UNIX socket - provides security benefits. You can indeed configure your setup to be weaker optimized - but as mentioned initially it seems to me that your reason for that is outdated.